# lower bound for the condition number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

I have shown that if we have an invertible matrix $A \in \mathcal{M}_{N}(\mathbb{R})$ and  $C \in \mathcal{M}_{N}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A+C$ is singular then $cond(A) \geq \frac{\mid \mid A \mid \mid }{\mid \mid C \mid \mid }.$

Now  given this matrix $  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & \alpha & \alpha  \\
1 & \alpha  & \alpha  \end{array} \right)$
 I want to use this result to find a lower bound $l_{\alpha}$ for $cond_{\infty} A$ such that $ \underset{\alpha \rightarrow 0} {\lim} l_{\alpha} = + \infty .$ Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $C=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&-\alpha&-\alpha\\0&-\alpha&-\alpha\end{pmatrix}$. If $\alpha$ is small, then $cond_{\infty}(A)\geq l_{\alpha}=\dfrac{3}{2|\alpha|}$.